# Entity framework with lambda to insert records into linked tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, lambda

My tables looks like this :

[image]

I am using entity framework with CRUD class files . First i would let user create an activity.

Then under the list of Activity , choose the activity that u want to create the task under which activity.

But how do i tied them using codes in ActivityTask table ? What i want to do is that the record will be auto generated at ActivityTask table where activityID is tied to a taskID whenever a certain task is being created under the selected activity .

Right now my codes are as simple as this :

```
        //Insert record 
     public void Insert(ModelSQL.task act)
     {
         context.tasks.AddObject(act);
     }
```

I am stucked at how to continue doing this . Do we have to use Include or something to include the link tables as well?

-EDIT-

```
//Insert record 
 public void Insert(ModelSQL.task act)
 {
     context.AddToActivityTasks(act);
     context.tasks.Include("ActivityTask");
     context.ActivityTasks.AddObject(act);
   //  context.tasks.AddObject(act);
 }
```

which 1 should i use? the first and 3rd option gives an invalid arguement error . Or none of them ?

Comment: A thought occurs: what are those other associations that appear at the lower right of your model, on ActivityTask? If you associate two tables with an intermediate table that has no fields other than the foreign keys, EF is supposed to be smart enough to create a many-to-many mapping (in EF5, anyway).

Comment: There are other tables that have a one to many relationship

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your UI lets a user select an `Activity` and a `Task` from select lists (dropdownlists) and that the value returned from each is the relevant ID, you'd create your `ActivityTask` like so:

```
public void InsertActivityTask(int actid, int taskid)
    context.activitytasks.AddObject(new ActivityTask
    { 
        activityID = actid, 
        taskID = taskid 
    });
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: there is no such thing as auto generate the records in ActivityTask when i create a task under an activity?

Comment: @user2376998 - It depends on the version of EF you're using and how your models are mapped, from what I recall. If your `Task` entity has an `Activities` property, then you should be able to use `task.Activities.Add(activity)`, assuming `task` is a `Task` entity and `activity` is an `Activity` entity that you created or queried for.

Comment: But in this case , they are not linked together , they are only linked through the ActivityTask table. So thats not possible?

Comment: @user2376998 Not as modeled, no. You may want to remove the intermediate table, if this is all it's used for. If your `Task` table has a foreign-key reference to `Activity`, EF will create a `Tasks` list property on each `Activity` entity and an `Activity` property on each `Task` entity. Is that a correct relationship (an activity can have many tasks, but a task can have only one activity)?

Comment: i forgot to remove the activityID from task table , but yes u are right , activity can have many task but a task can only tied to an activity

Comment: @user2376998 Then leave the `activityID` on `task`, make sure you create the relationship in the database, and then recreate those models. You'll find that EF builds the properties I mentioned above.

Comment: Actually i had activityID on task with relationship until i was told to remove it because i was told that we should tie them in another table .

Comment: i have the option of context.ActivityTask.(something) .. weird thing is it doesn't reflect on the edmx model of the table ( activitytask) that link both activity and task